# Xcode server can't be connected

Tags: xcode

I select Xcode in the Server app sidebar, and turn on Xcode, then Click Choose button to select Xcode.app in the Applications folder, but Server just hold on there for a long time with message 'Waiting for Xcode setup to complete...', and it remains the same after I change to a different Xcode or OS X Server, it's very annoying. The following log is found in system.log from Console app.

```
xcscontrol[7289]: Xcode version: 6.1 (6A1046a) (OS X SDK 13F26, iOS SDK 12B407)
xcscontrol[7289]: Server version: 4 (14S333)
xcscontrol[7289]: OS X version: 10.10 (14A389)
xcscontrol[7289]: [XCSHTTPResponse] Received an unexpected error: -1004 (Could not connect to the server.) - GET https://127.0.0.1:20344/api/versions
```

Comment: "sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset"

I find a solution from     https://devforums.apple.com/message/1053273#1053273, it works really fine!!

Comment: This also helped with my other problem: after the latest Yosemite update I couldn't start Xcode in OS X Server. After running this command, it works again. Thanks!